btrfs destroy qgroup after removing subvolume failed with Device or resource busy
When I remove a subvolume, I want to destroy the corresponding qgroup. but destroy will fail almost 35 seconds. and the btrfs subvolume sync stucked 16s
subvolume_id=`btrfs inspect-internal rootid /run/nas/disk0/user0`
btrfs subvolume delete --commit-after /run/nas/disk0/user0
TIME=%e time btrfs subvolume sync /run/nas/disk0 $subvolume_id

uptime
while true ; do
        btrfs qgroup destroy $subvolume_id /run/nas/disk0 && break
        sleep 5
done
uptime

the output is:
Delete subvolume (commit): '/run/nas/disk0/user0'
Subvolume id 257 is gone
16.00
 19:54:55 up 1 day, 14:19,  7 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.03, 0.00
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
ERROR: unable to destroy quota group: Device or resource busy
 19:55:30 up 1 day, 14:19,  7 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.03, 0.00

why get busy, subvolume is removed already. How can I gracefully remove the qgroup without wait so long.
